# Why does Firefox keep creating a ~/Desktop folder?

Tags: desktop, firefox

This is more of a puzzle than a problem:

Every time I start Firefox, a "Desktop" folder is created in my home folder (home/me/Desktop).  I delete it, use Firefox, it comes back.

Am I sure it's Firefox?

I have a basic, default installation (Freya), which has been updated.  The only changes I made were to remove Midori and add Firefox.  I did some trial-and-error and it only happens (and always happens) after starting Firefox.

I could live with it, I suppose, but the voices in my head are anal-retentive and being all ocd fussy about it. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set your `$HOME` directory as `Desktop` in xdg-user-dirs config file (~/.config/user-dirs.dirs).

This can be done manually through text editor. Open this file:

```
scratch-text-editor ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

And add this line to the end of file:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: I confess, I was hoping for a way to stop Firefox's annoying behaviour.  Your idea is to trick Firefox into thinking it's already been done.  Very clever workaround.

Answer (score 1):

This is a re-hash of a very good [post](https://www.kariliq.nl/misc/firefox-dirs.html) about this, but I'm including this for other like me who might stumble here and who want to understand a bit more about why this is happening

> The reason why Firefox insists on creating these directories is that it follows a freedesktop.org practice attempting to standardise how applications use “well known” directories.
>
> Fortunately, however, this standard also offers a way to prevent Firefox from creating these directories.
>
> Edit the ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs file so that it has the following contents.

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/"
```

If `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` does not exist, you can simply create it

Comment: That link really misrepresents the user-dirs.dirs file as a Firefox thing when it's really a Linux-desktop thing.  Worse still, it's advice, would disable all 'known' directories, including ones Firefox doesn't even use.  Skip the page you linked and go right to the page it links: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs/.